# Find the Chebyshev Norm of f.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Find the Chebyshev Norm $\|f\|_\infty$ of $f(x)=(x^2-2x+2)^{e^{-x}}$ $x \in [0,\infty]$

Am I right in understanding its the supremum of the function? and if the function is bounded then its the maximum?

If someone could clarify what the Chebyshev norm involves, (I believe its more commonly called the infinity norm) and how its applied to this example, that would be amazing. Thank you

Comment: It is the $\sup$ of $|f|$. If $f(x) = 1-e^{-x}$, then $\|f\|_\infty = 1$, but the function has no $\max$.

Comment: would $\|f\|_\infty$ = $2$ in this case?

Comment: I believe that it is $\|f\|_\infty = 1$ for the $f$ in the question.